# Google IoT JWT expiration

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot

Which is the maximun life of a JWT to use with Google Cloud IoT?

I have seen this [JWT](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/jwts#jwt_claims) but i'm not sure about how to use this:

*The maximum lifetime of a token is 24 hours + skew*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you link is correct. The maximum life of a JWT token for IoT is 24 hours. Although it mentions skew, I recommend against including that in the life-time of a token as it's intended as a buffer zone so that if your clock is a few minutes ahead of Google's no early expiration will occur.

What this means in practice is Google will accept JWT tokens with an `exp` field that between now and one day from now.

What this means for you, is that when you create a JWT token, you should set the exp field to the current time + 24 hours (or less, if you want to refresh more often).

Comment: And there are any way to increase the maximun life? For example, If you use a MQTT device where you can not auto-change the password field with the new JWT, what could we do?

Comment: There is no way to increase the maximum life. Google requires this to reduce the damage that can be done if a JWT is stolen. Perhaps talk to the device manufacturer?